# ConstraintLayout - how to wrap over RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a ConstraintLayout with an appBar (containing a toolbar), two fragments (containing a RecyclerView each) and a button at the bottom.

What I am trying to do is to wrap the height of the layout over the size of the RecyclerViews. As you can see on the picture below, every Recyclerview is taking an equal height regardless of the size of the list.

[image]

And this is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/template_grey_light"
    tools:context=".presentation.ui.activity.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/AppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragmentTop"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/AppBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragmentBottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragmentTop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/shuffleButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shuffleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/template_love_red"
        android:text="Go!"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragmentBottom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I understand I am having 0dp on the height attributes and that makes it equal in height, but then if I don't, everything will overlap at the top. Any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: You want make the fragments height as the same of recyclerview inside them?

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal. Right now they have a fixed height

Comment: Use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in your `FragmentContainerView` tag

Comment: Thanks, that works. The problem now is that all the views are centered, leaving a gap between the toolbar and the top. Same at the bottom, there is a gap between the button and the bottom of the screen

Comment: Check if you recyclerview has margins or padding. Check also for gravity in your layout inside the fragments

Comment: No margins or padding. I managed to solve it by removing app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragmentTop". Anyway, your comment helped me to solve the main problem, so if you want to create an answer, I will accept it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214059/discussion-between-giuseppe-criscione-and-user6920323).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in your `FragmentContainerView` tag